# why Hash table time complexity is o(1)

Tags: arrays, data-structures, time-complexity, runtime, hashtable

if hashtables are arrays under the hood, then why its time complexity is o(1) for insert and delete operations.
will it be stored as free memory slots rather than back to back memory slots?
why we are not considering that copy operation for hashtable itself?

I tried searching for some online references but no significant answer is found.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the hash table implementations have `O(1)` complexity on inserts and deletes in what called amortized time. That means that occasionally an operation might indeed take large amount of time (e.g. order of magnitude `N` - the number of elements in the table), but on any given infinite sequence of insert/delete queries average amount of operations per query will be limited by a constant. This is similar to a simple dynamic array's inserts being `O(1)` in amortized time even though occasionally an insert will cause full copy of an array which is definitely not a constant time operation.

Answer (score 4):

Hastables are arrays of `linkedlists` or `binary search trees` in some occasions.

- **Why is deleting O(1)?**
  **Ans:** While you delete a key, you first calculate it's hash and then you know which exact position the key is in the array. The operation is `O(1)` as you go directly there and delete the key.
- **Why is inserting O(1)?**
  **Ans:** Same as above.
- **Will it be stored as free memory slots rather than back to back memory slots?**
  **Ans:** yes, that is the point of creating a bucket. It would be empty. When the size reaches a particular limit, the buckets will reconstructed and the size will be increased. But this does not happen often and does not affect the overall time complexity.